# How does Mathematica factor expression with derivatives (i.e. not polynomial)?

Tags: factorization

I was surprised Mathematica did this automatically. I have an ode and wanted to factor it. I did not think `Factor` will work and I need to write special code to do it. But Mathematica did it

```
ClearAll[y, x];
odeLHS = y'[x]*y[x]*y''[x] + y'[x]^2*y[x] + y'[x]*y[x]
```

We see by looking at the above that $y y'$ is a factor. So

```
List @@ Factor[odeLHS]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So it broke the ode into 3 products which is what I wanted. But how did it do it since it is not a polynomial.

Only reference I found is in the help, under [Advanced Uses](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factor.html?view=all) it says

> Some non-polynomial expressions can be factored:

But **some** is not very clear to me. On what basis does it do it? Could one predict beforehand if `Factor` will work or not on an expression? How did `Factor` work on non-polynomials?

btw, in Maple, the `factor()` command does not work on this since not polynomial., and I had to write special code to factor on an ode. So this is much easier in Mathematica to do.

V 13.2

Comment: Have you tried `PolynomialQ[odeLHS, Variables[odeLHS]]`? And perhaps `Variables[odeLHS]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that `Factor` has just treated those derivatives as new variables. This can be verified with:

```
odeLHS /. Derivative[n_][y_] :> Symbol[ToString@y <> ToString@n] // Factor
(* y[x] y1[x] (1 + y1[x] + y2[x]) *)
```